# Android Kotlin: "java.lang.NullPointerException: Parameter specified as non-null is null" on initialization of data class with default values

Tags: android, kotlin

Kotlin noob question..

As part of the [Hyperskill Stopwatch with Productivity Timer](https://hyperskill.org/projects/72?track=16) solution, I wrote this piece of source code:

```kotlin
data class StopwatchViewState(
    val elapsed: String = "00:00"
)

class StopwatchViewModel : ViewModel(){
    // TODO without specifying `elapsed` in the constructor call, this throws a NullPointerException. Why, as it
    //  has a default value set in its default constructor??
    private val _state = MutableStateFlow(StopwatchViewState())
    val state: StateFlow<StopwatchViewState> = _state.asStateFlow()
    
    // snip
```

When I run Hyperskill's automated tests against this code, I get this stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "SDK 29 Main Thread @coroutine#2" java.lang.NullPointerException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method org.hyperskill.stopwatch.StopwatchViewState.$$robo$$org_hyperskill_stopwatch_StopwatchViewState$__constructor__, parameter elapsed
    at org.hyperskill.stopwatch.StopwatchViewState.__constructor__(StopwatchViewModel.kt)
    at org.hyperskill.stopwatch.StopwatchViewState.<init>(StopwatchViewModel.kt)
    at org.hyperskill.stopwatch.StopwatchViewModel.__constructor__(StopwatchViewModel.kt:16)
    at org.hyperskill.stopwatch.StopwatchViewModel.<init>(StopwatchViewModel.kt)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
...
```

If I replace

`private val _state = MutableStateFlow(StopwatchViewState())`

with

`private val _state = MutableStateFlow(StopwatchViewState("00:00"))`

the same test passes.

Under what circumstances can this happen, or what am I misunderstanding here?

---

UPDATE 23-12-24: [GitHub issue](https://github.com/mjfroehlich/Stopwatch_with_Productivity_Timer/issues/1) with all details and source code.

---

UPDATE 2023-12-16: Full stack trace

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Exception. Test failed on activity execution with java.lang.NullPointerException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method org.hyperskill.stopwatch.StopwatchViewState.$$robo$$org_hyperskill_stopwatch_StopwatchViewState$__constructor__, parameter elapsed
java.lang.NullPointerException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method org.hyperskill.stopwatch.StopwatchViewState.$$robo$$org_hyperskill_stopwatch_StopwatchViewState$__constructor__, parameter elapsed
    at org.hyperskill.stopwatch.StopwatchViewState.__constructor__(StopwatchViewModel.kt)
    at org.hyperskill.stopwatch.StopwatchViewState.<init>(StopwatchViewModel.kt)
    at org.hyperskill.stopwatch.StopwatchViewModel.__constructor__(StopwatchViewModel.kt:16)
    at org.hyperskill.stopwatch.StopwatchViewModel.<init>(StopwatchViewModel.kt)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.ReflectionFactory.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$NewInstanceFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.java:219)
    at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.java:278)
    at androidx.lifecycle.SavedStateViewModelFactory.create(SavedStateViewModelFactory.java:112)
    at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:185)
    at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:150)
    at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelLazy.getValue(ViewModelProvider.kt:54)
    at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelLazy.getValue(ViewModelProvider.kt:41)
    at org.hyperskill.stopwatch.MainActivity.onCreate$lambda-0(MainActivity.kt:21)
    at org.hyperskill.stopwatch.MainActivity.onCreate$lambda-1(MainActivity.kt:23)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7140)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowView$_View_$$Reflector22.performClick(Unknown Source)
    at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowView.performClick(ShadowView.java:238)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java)
    at org.hyperskill.tests.stopwatch.internals.AbstractUnitTest.clickAndRun(AbstractUnitTest.kt:155)
    at org.hyperskill.tests.stopwatch.Stage2UnitTest$checkCountOneSecondAfterOneSecondOnStartButtonClick$1.invoke(Stage2UnitTest.kt:79)
    at org.hyperskill.tests.stopwatch.Stage2UnitTest$checkCountOneSecondAfterOneSecondOnStartButtonClick$1.invoke(Stage2UnitTest.kt:76)
    at org.hyperskill.tests.stopwatch.internals.AbstractUnitTest.testActivity(AbstractUnitTest.kt:84)
    at org.hyperskill.tests.stopwatch.internals.AbstractUnitTest.testActivity$default(AbstractUnitTest.kt:75)
    at org.hyperskill.tests.stopwatch.Stage2UnitTest.checkCountOneSecondAfterOneSecondOnStartButtonClick(Stage2UnitTest.kt:76)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:56)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$HelperTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:591)
    at org.robolectric.internal.SandboxTestRunner$2.lambda$evaluate$0(SandboxTestRunner.java:274)
    at org.robolectric.internal.bytecode.Sandbox.lambda$runOnMainThread$0(Sandbox.java:88)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

    at org.hyperskill.tests.stopwatch.internals.AbstractUnitTest.testActivity(AbstractUnitTest.kt:86)
    at org.hyperskill.tests.stopwatch.internals.AbstractUnitTest.testActivity$default(AbstractUnitTest.kt:75)
    at org.hyperskill.tests.stopwatch.Stage2UnitTest.checkCountOneSecondAfterOneSecondOnStartButtonClick(Stage2UnitTest.kt:76)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:56)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$HelperTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:591)
    at org.robolectric.internal.SandboxTestRunner$2.lambda$evaluate$0(SandboxTestRunner.java:274)
    at org.robolectric.internal.bytecode.Sandbox.lambda$runOnMainThread$0(Sandbox.java:88)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: `at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect...` I don't know what is this environment but apparently there is some java reflection going under the hood which is prone to ignoring kotlin metadata and default args. Code itself looks fine.

Comment: yeah, like Pawel mentioned, i don't believe this has anything to do with kotlin itself, this is more likely related to whatever framework you're using

Comment: Thank you! I have added the full stack trace for context

Comment: In Kotlin you can declare a default value for a parameter in a class constructor which works fine alone but when using frameworks or libraries they use other mechanisms to create objects, so they might not be fully aware of Kotlin's defaults especially if the tool is more Java-focused. So I think this is causing the issue. This has nothing to do with Kotlin so study deeply the frameworks that you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the beginning of your stacktrace. The test objects are created indirectly, through reflection. Look at this:

```
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.ReflectionFactory.newInstance(Unknown Source)
```

newInstance() is a java reflection method that invokes a constructor with no arguments from the target class. Default parameters translate to extra method declarations. So, from java's perspective, the values of your model class are never set in the default constructor, and you get that crash. That's why adding a default constructor with the parameters set works. Default parameters are syntactic sugar, so they won't work at low level.

On a side note, avoid embedding classes, specially when state/lifecycle management is present. You tend to treat both classes as a unit, but their lifecycles are different, and in real world targets, you will get in trouble. You want an example? Asynctask. ALL their problems were due to people blindly following Google's examples, embedding them into other classes, directly read members of both, and then crashing due to one of them being absent. All those issues go away if you use listeners, which can be voided at the right lifcycle phase.

Answer (score -1):

You have declared your Data class parameter as non-null, which expects non-null value all the time, in your case, instance of `StopwatchViewState()` may be passed as null, from test cases or else where in the code, which throws NullPointerException, if you explicitly pass value like this `StopwatchViewState("00:00")` you are ensuring that value is not null to the compiler, so it passes. To avoid the Exception you can use Elvis operator or secondary constructor to handle this scenario.

```
data class StopwatchViewState(val elapsed: String) {
    constructor(elapsed: String?) : this(elapsed ?: "00:00")
}
```

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure I'm following..  what do you mean with "instance of StopwatchViewState() may be passed as null"? The runtime complains that `elapsed` is null, and the execption happens while StopwatchViewState is constructed. `elapsed` has default value of "00:00" defined, so
`Log.i("Calculator", "elapsed: ${StopwatchViewState().elapsed}")` logs `elapsed: 00:00`